# Getting Prime Number without loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to determine if a number is prime or not without using a loop.
Below is what I have so far. My quarrel is that I don't know if that will cover all possible input values.

```
bool isPrime(int Value)
{
   if ((Value % 2 == 0) || (Value % 3 == 0) || (Value % 5 == 0) || (Value % 7 == 0))
       return false;
   else
       return true;
}
```

Comment: You can try to generate a [prime sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) and then probe into it, but I think generating the sieve itself would violate your non-loop requirement.

Comment: does work for 11- will return true because none of those numbers will divide into 11.

Comment: No, it won't cover the range of all non-negative integers. If you input is limited to less than that, then that's an important detail to add to your question.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work for 2, 3, 5 and 7. Brillant.

Comment: Won't work for 121, it will say its prime, when its not, as its divisible by 11.

Comment: This belongs in mathematics. Also, a quick google search would give no end to primeness algorithms.

Comment: @JustinHarvey: or 143, 187, 209, 253, or 319

Comment: @Aron OP is probably a student who has been challenged with a problem which has partial, imperfect solutions.  I've had somewhat related question asked as part of coding exercise for an interview.  So the question is valid. The answer is not straight forward.

Comment: @LB2 the point is however there is no perfect solution at the moment. Prime number research has been at the forefront of mathematical research for centuries. One of the Clay Institute prizes is in a way, related to this actual problem. Then to ask how to do it without loops...suggests to me that he wants to get primeness in constant time. Its like asking someone to build a computer more powerful than all the computers in the world, AND then do it without transistors...or valves...or metal....or atoms.

Comment: There is NO WAY to find if any number is a prime number without a loop.

Comment: @krimog : probably true, but can you prove it? ;)

Comment: @krimog I think Shor's Algorithm might not need loops. Assuming you can do FT without loops (possibly Optically). [If you ask IBM really nicely you could borrow their computer, if, like, you don't know if 15 is prime or not, in polynomial time.](http://www-03.ibm.com/press/us/en/pressrelease/965.wss)

Comment: @spender: If only... I could use the money I'd earn :p
Aron: Should have been more precise in the first place : "There is NO WAY in C# to find...". I mean, quantum calculation hasn't been implemented yet.

Comment: @krimog Shor it has! Just not a usable large one yet.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely not cover the full range of prime numbers. You're are currently checking if your input is divided by 4 prime numbers. To be sure that your number is prime it has to be not divisible by any other prime number as well (13, 17, 23 etc.). The far worse alternative of a loop is recursion but I see no reason why you should go with the latter.

[You can use this method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/prime)

Comment: Erm, those examples use loops, and the questioner is asking how to do it without a loop

Comment: You're right. But such thing is not possible unless you hardcode each prime number in your if statement or go with recursion.

Comment: @NikolayPetkov I'm sorry but Euclid proved that was impossible. You know...like over 2000 years ago. Didn't you get the memo?

Answer (score 1):

If you can define the scope of *possible inputs* to something, say non-zero integers below 100, then something like this might be the simplest solution

```
int[] primes = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97 } ;

bool isPrime(int Value)
{
    return primes.Contains(Value);
}
```

Comment: You should put it in a `HashSet`...you know...just because...

Comment: @Aron: True enough. Probably doesn't make much difference with <100, but as your set gets larger it would probably be better.

Comment: I'd venture that this uses loops (albeit, hidden from view in the implementation of `.Contains`)

Comment: @spender Nope. `HashSet.Contains` doesn't use loops! Thats why its fast!

Comment: @Aron: A comment to the answer, not your comment...

Comment: @spender: Wow! That is really splitting hairs. In that case, so with the `HashSet` as Aron suggested. Or just hardcode it in a massive `if` statement: `if (Value != 2 && Value != 3 && Value != 5 &&...)`